# Why type annotation is not directly supported by java 8 compiler or Eclipse

Tags: java, java-8, type-annotation

Currently I am researching on the new features of Java8: `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html`

From the link above, it is clearly demonstrated:

`Type Annotations provide the ability to apply an annotation anywhere a type is used, not just on a declaration. Used with a pluggable type system, this feature enables improved type checking of your code.`

But when I tried to add type annotation such as `@NotNull` or `@Readonly` etc. in Eclipse Neon, it can not recognize these annotations at all! This is way frustrating.

Did I miss something? or if I need to do more configuration like adding extra jars, how come this is still listed as the Java 8 new feature?

Comment: Do you have configured java8 in your eclipse?

Comment: I think so, as my code includes lots of lambda expressions and they are accepted anyway

Comment: Think so id not enough. You should know it

Comment: I actually do not know why

Comment: add a screenshow of your Project please

Comment: Eclipse does support one set of type annotations out of the box: `@NonNull` and friends, see http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_type_annotations.htm

Answer (score 0):

@Jens Thanks :) I searched again from Google and found the following link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html

In the linked page, it was told `The Java SE 8 release does not provide a type checking framework, but it allows you to write (or download) a type checking framework that is implemented as one or more pluggable modules that are used in conjunction with the Java compiler.`

So the key is to have a `checker framework` either DIY or by using existing `checker framework`. In the end of the the linked page, there is another link page of an existing `Checker Framework` - https://checkerframework.org/ and this one is probably so far the best framework we can use :)